# How to check for double click in Bevy rust

Tags: input, rust, mouse, bevy

New to bevy and need to implement a double click system into my game and this is what I tried. I got a couple errors specifically relating to the local variable containing Instant. I have properly imported the instant crate but am not sure what else is needed in bevy to make a local var work.

```rust
pub fn double_click(
    mouse_button_input: Res<Input<MouseButton>>,
    mut double_click_time: Local<Instant>,
) {
    if mouse_button_input.just_pressed(MouseButton::Left) {
        double_click_time = Instant::now();
    }

    println!("Time: {}", double_click_time.elapsed().as_secs());
}
```

One error I am getting is at the `Instant::now();` and it is

```
expected struct `bevy::prelude::Local<'_, Instant, >`
   found struct `Instant
```

Also where the system is added it gives error

```
the trait bound `for<'r, 's> fn(bevy::prelude::Res<'r, bevy::prelude::Input<bevy::prelude::MouseButton>>, bevy::prelude::Local<'s, Instant>) {inventory::double_click}: IntoSystem<(), (), _>` is not satisfied
```

If there is another way to detect a double click, that works too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error and [the docs for `Local`](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/prelude/struct.Local.html) (which say that it implements `Deref` and `DerefMut`), you just need to assign to the *contents* of the `Local`, and that should fix your compile error:

```rust
        *double_click_time = Instant::now();
```

I don't know Bevy, so I don't know if this is actually the best way to handle double clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that worked but I figured out another way, I just implememnted the double click timeout into a global struct used for a couple other related things.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).